# ArrayList adding objects - no suitable method found for add

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

I have a piece of code designed to gather a list of files from a second file, format them into  "Statistic" objects and individual arrays before finally adding each individual object to an ArrayList.  Unfortunately, I'm getting the error no suitable method found for add(int, Statistic).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The corresponding code is as follows.

```
    Statistic tempStatistic=new Statistic(); 
    Statistic[] statisticsToAdd=new Statistic[importFileList.size()];

    ArrayList<Statistic> totalStatistics=new ArrayList<Statistic>();
    for (int i=0; i<totalStatistics.size(); i++) {  
        statisticsToAdd=getStatistics(importFileList.get(i)); 

        for (int j=0; j<statisticsToAdd.length; j++) {
            //statisticsToAdd[j]=new Statistic();
            tempStatistic=statisticsToAdd[j];
            totalStatistics.add(tempStatistic);
        }//end inner FOR
    }//end outer FOR


    Statistic[] totalStatisticsArray=totalStatistics.toArray();
```

return totalStatisticsArray;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your totalStatistics variable is of the wrong type. It sems it should be:

```
ArrayList<Statistic> totalStatistics=new ArrayList<Statistic>();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but now I'm getting another error, "required Statistic[], found: Object".  I've added more to the code I listed.

Comment: Try this: Statistic[] totalStatisticsArray=totalStatistics.toArray(new Statistic[0]);

Comment: That worked, thank you so much.  Can I ask why the 0?

Comment: According to the api doc in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[]): the parameter is "the array into which the elements of the list are to be stored, if it is big enough; otherwise, a new array of the same runtime type is allocated for this purpose.". So if you pass an array of size 0 then a new array will be allocated to fit the amount of objects in the arraylist.